# Drag to "visible tabs" while editing the tab bar on the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, usability, navigation

The current design requires you to press the + or - buttons on the left of each tab to make it visible on the menu bar or not while editing on the iOS SE app.

> [image]

The design can be improved if dragging the tabs from the "more options" list to the visible tabs list are allowed, instead of only allowing the tabs to be dragged inside a single list. It will be more convenient for people to edit the menu bar.

Current app version is 1.6.2.5.